# Add OAuth2 authentication server to ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, authorization

I have to write project in ASP.NET MVC 5 - I am aware of ASP.NET Core, but instructions for platform were clear. For now, I have great problem with integrating OAuth2 authorization. In ASP.NET Core adding authorization server was just:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddJwtBearer(o =>
    {
        o.Authority = "http://localhost:5000"; //custom OAuth2 server
        o.Audience = "resourceapi";
        o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    });

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("ApiReader", policy => policy.RequireClaim("scope", "api.read"));
        options.AddPolicy("Consumer", policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "consumer"));
        ...
    }
```

(I am using Password flow). Finding this took me few weeks. I can't find anything similar for ASP.NET MVC 5. Any help?